# SwiftUI create list

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I have an array of data and I'm trying to display it in a list like the example in WWDC
I do not have macOS Catalina but i'm using the simulator so I think it should be fine.

If I replace `List(rooms)` with `List(0..<5)` for ex it will work but when I try to pass an array it wont display anything, just some empty rows.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var rooms: [Room] = []

    var body: some View {
        List(rooms) { room in

            Image(systemName: "photo")

            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(room.name)
                Text("\(room.capacity) people").font(.subheadline).foregroundColor(.secondary)
            }
        }

    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(rooms: testData)
    }
}
```

My data is here

```
import SwiftUI

struct Room: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var capacity: Int
    var hasVideo: Bool = false
    var imageName: String { return name }
    var thumbnailName: String { return name + "Thumb" }
}

#if DEBUG
let testData = [
    Room(name: "Observation Deck", capacity: 6, hasVideo: true),
    Room(name: "Executive Suite", capacity: 8, hasVideo: false),
    Room(name: "Charter Jet", capacity: 16, hasVideo: true),
    Room(name: "Dungeon", capacity: 10, hasVideo: true),
]
#endif
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: you can refer this --> https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/building-lists-and-navigation

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `ForEach`

Like:

```
List {
  ForEach(rooms, id: \.id) { room in
         //Display rooms
  }
}
```

Comment: `Type '_' has no member 'id'` and when I do just `ForEach(rooms)` it doesn;t show anything

Comment: That is strange. I tested in in a playground and it works for me.
```
var body: some View {
        List() {
            ForEach( rooms) { room in
                Image(systemName: "photo")
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(room.name)
                    Text("\(room.capacity) people").font(.subheadline).foregroundColor(.secondary)
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: Same code? Could it be macOS Catalina. Im still using the old one

Comment: Yes, I copied your code. Good question - do you have the newest Xcode version(Version 11.2 (11B52))? 
Do you program for iOS or macOS?

Comment: When I build the app from wwdc tutorial it works fine but my code dosnt

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add my data to `rooms` array. Since I can not use Canvas or preview `[]` means that I have no data so `var rooms: [Room] = [..., ...]`